# Update and set row where id is equal to an id in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set 2 columns in a row, where the paymentid of that row is the same as the foreign key in another table to that row.

```
UPDATE 
    SomeDB.dbo.[Payment]
SET 
    TransactionId = {0},
    PaymentAccepted = 1
WHERE
```

I have an `OrderId`, and that Order has a `PaymentId` foreign key to the Payment table.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is what you're looking for, but without having concrete fields and table names, I can only give you a hint how it will work.

```
Update 
    SomeDB.dbo.[Payment]
SET 
    TransactionId = {0},
    PaymentAccepted = 1
FROM 
    SomeDB.dbo.[Payment]
INNER JOIN 
    SomeDB.dbo.[OtherTable] on SomeDB.dbo.[Payment].paymentId = SomeDB.dbo.[OtherTable].foreignKey
WHERE
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work for you ...

```
Update SomeDB.dbo.[Payment]
SET TransactionId = {0}, PaymentAccepted = 1
FROM SomeDB.dbo.[Payment] A
INNER JOIN SomeDB.dbo.[SomeTable] B on A.ForeignID = B.ID
WHERE B.SomeColumn = {1}
```